# A Differential Equation with two functions and two derivatives

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations

Let $a(x)$ is a function of $x$ and $ b(y) $ is a function of $y.$

I am only interested in the relationship between $a(x)$ and $b(y)$ but the generic question is:

Solve for $x$ and $y$ if

$$ \frac{\partial a(x)} {a(x)\partial x} =\frac{\partial b(y)} {b(y) \partial y} $$
and 
$$ x + y = c $$ 
where $c>0$ is a constant.

---

My attempt, please let me know if it's correct?

Subtituting $y = c - x$ and $\partial y = - \partial x$.

Multiplying both sides with $dx$, the equation becomes:

$$ \frac{\partial a(x)dx} {a(x)\partial x} =\frac{\partial b(c-x)dx} {b(c-x) \partial (c-x)} $$
Take infinite integral of both sides, we have:

$ln(a(x)=-ln(b(c-x)$ hence:

$x, y$ will satisfy that: 
$$a(x) = \frac{1}{b(y)}$$

Comment: You are presuming that $a(x) b(c-x) = 1$, but it could be any non zero constant.

Comment: Yes you are right! Thanks. So is $a(x)b(c-x) = T$ is the correct answer?

Comment: If $T\neq 0$. Differentiate to check!